# How to count mean values for repeated values in a table pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datatable, pandas-groupby

I have this table:

[image]

I need to calculate mean 'INCOME' value for each technology. But the problem is that technologies are repeated through the table:

[image]

So how can I do that?

Comment: Does this give you the correct result? `data.groupby('TECHNOLOGY').mean()`

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks!

Comment: Great, np mate.